# Using percentages for divs

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, percentage, zooming

I'm using a container with a fixed width. Inside the container I have 2 divs floating left, the first div has a width of 9% and the second div has a width of 91% but for some reason there is a 1px white line that shows up on the very right. How do I fix this issue? It sometimes varies when zooming on the browser.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main-container">

       <div id="container1">
       </div> 
       <div id="container2">
       </div>     

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#main-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 45px;
    width: 1110px;
    height: 650px;
    border: 3px solid red;
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px; }

/*content*/

#container1 {
    float: left;
    width: 9%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 7px 0px 0px 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px 0px 0px 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px 0px 0px 7px;
    background: yellow; }

#container2 {
    float: left;
    width: 91%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 0 7px 7px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 7px 7px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 7px 7px 0;
    background: orange; }
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gw5AH/)

Comment: Someone will be able to provide a better answer, but this is most likely due to sub-pixel issues as the browser tries to convert your percentages to whole number pixel values. If the percentages equate to decimal values, the browser has to round the numbers to display on screen - some browsers handle this better than others.

Comment: As a workaround, you could set the background color of the main-container to be the same as the right div: background: orange;

Comment: So how do I go about fixing this? I was advised to start using responsive design instead of using fixed widths and heights all of the time. I usually don't have a problem using fixed widths and heights but the problem with that is when you start zooming in and out it would cause divs to move out of alignment. Any ideas?

Comment: @SteveWellens thanks for the comment Steve. That is true but I didn't really want to cut corners and use that as a solution. The main reason i'm using percentages in the first place is because of an alignment issue when zooming in and out of the page. I have had the same problems with a navigation I was working on. Here is a link to the code. http://jsfiddle.net/vzuS7/1/ How can I resolve all of these alignment issues?

Answer (score 0):

As the some others mentions it looks like the problem is caused by rounding differences in WebKit.

Your can add `float: right;` to the second container to fix the alignment and remove the gap. http://jsfiddle.net/Gw5AH/3/

Comment: Thanks for the comment Dan, but that doesn't fix the problem either, all that does is creates a 1px  gap between the yellow and orange divs.